# Using StreamPlot and Manipulate to show the field lines with varying the parameters

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I have the equation
$$\dot{x}=F(x(t);\mu,\lambda)=\mu x-\lambda x^2+3$$
and I want to use `StreamPlot` and `Manipulate` to vary $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

The code for an example how it should look like:

```
Manipulate[
StreamPlot[{y, -λ - μ x + x^3}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   StreamScale -> Large, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"λ = ", λ, " ,  μ = ", μ}]], 
{λ, -1, 1}, {μ, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: How does your function depend upon $y$?

Comment: It only depends on x, no y.

Comment: So why use a `StreamPlot`, which displays functions of two variables ($x$ and $y$)?

Comment: Is there any other possibility to show the field lines with varying $\lambda$ and $\mu$? And when I use $y$ for a Dummy?

Comment: It makes no sense to use $y$ for a "dummy".  You can plot ${\partial x \over \partial t}$ versus $x$.  (See solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as stated makes little sense.  A StreamPlot shows $y$ and $x$.  If you let the horizontal axis be $x$ and the vertical be the derivative of $x$, then:

```
Manipulate[
 StreamPlot[{x, -λ x^2 + μ x + 3}, 
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    StreamScale -> Large, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"λ = ", λ, " ,  μ = ", μ}]], 
  {λ, -1, 1}, {μ, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: I tried it with

    `Manipulate[StreamPlot[{y, -λ x^2 + μ x + 3}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    StreamScale -> Large, PlotLabel -> Row[{"λ = ", λ, " ,  μ = ", μ}]], 
    {λ, -1, 1}, {μ, -1, 1}]`

I want to characterize my equlibrium points with analysing the and direction of the field lines, and this only possible when I use $y$ instead of $x$ in your code...
I dont know if this make sense, but I get my fieldlines.