# Projection of a 3D ODE solution on a parametric 2D streamplot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d

#### Problem

I have a third-order dynamical system of which I'd like to plot the solutions on the streamplot defined by the same dynamical system, as a function of one of the three variables.

These are the equations:

\begin{align*}
x^\prime &= (1 - z) (A (1 - x) - x)\\
y^\prime &= B - (1 - z) y\\
z^\prime &= z (1 - z)
\end{align*}
I would like to plot a projection of the trajectory on the (x, y) plane, as a function of the value the variable z assumes. I can treat z almost as it were a parameter, its solution being an invertible function of time.

#### What I've done so far

Taking inspiration from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140226/using-streamplot-and-manipulate-to-show-the-field-lines-with-varying-the-paramet), I was able to plot the parametic streamplot (corresponding to stacks of the ideal 3D phase diagram as a function of z) and the solution of 3D dynamical system *separately*:

```
splot = Manipulate[StreamPlot[
{
(1 - z) (A (1 - x) - x),
B - (1 - z) y
},
{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 5}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
StreamScale -> Large, StreamPoints ->Fine], {z, 0, 1}];

pplot = ParametricPlot3D[
Evaluate[
First[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. 
NDSolve[
{
x'[t] == (1 - z[t]) (A (1 - x[t]) - x[t]), 
y'[t] == B - (1 - z[t]) y[t],
z'[t] == z[t] (1 - z[t])
Thread[{x[0], y[0], z[0]} == {0.1, 0, 0.01}]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]]],
{t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
```

How to superimpose `splot` and `pplot`, always being able to vary the value of `z`? Of course, `Show[splot, pplot]` does not work...

#### What I would like to do

In summary, I'd like to obtain a 2D projection of the 3D solution of the dynamical system, and plot it onto a streamplot defined by the (x, y) field, as a function of the value the variable z assumes.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Just try `ParametricPlot3D` and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, with ParametricPlot3D I can get the 3D trajectory. Thanks! But still how to project it on the 2D streamplot? I still obtain "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show"

Comment: How is this possible? Your `3D` has `x`, `y` and `z` but in `StreamPlot` you have just `x` and `y`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but I had to remove any dependence from z in the streamplot if I wanted to obtain the plot. Ideally, I'd like to have the complete form that you can see in the NDSolve part in the streamplot, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, this can motivate desired answer:

```
f[a_, b_, x_, y_, z_] := {(1 - z) (a (1 - x) - x), b - (1 - z) y, 
  z (1 - z)}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == 
     f[a, b, x[t], y[t], z[t]],
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b,
     x0, y0, z0}];
s1 = Show[
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{x[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t], 
       y[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   StreamPlot[f[1, 1, x, y, 0.1][[;; 2]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}], 
   Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "z=0.1", ImageSize -> 300];
s2 = Show[
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{x[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t], 
       y[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   StreamPlot[f[1, 1, x, y, 0.2][[;; 2]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}], 
   Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "z=0.2", ImageSize -> 300];
p = ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[{x[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t], y[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t], 
      z[1, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{s1, s2, p}]
```

[image]